# PostgreSQL V and W in the same result

Tags: postgresql

In a stock locater based system we have many different stock locater codes, in this example LVH001 to LVH999 and LWH001 to LWH999. When we run the following select statement

```
select * 
from verkstad.lager 
where lgrplats1 >= 'LVH000' 
and lgrplats1 <= 'LVH999' 
ORDER BY lgrplats1;
```

The result includes the LWH*** stock locater codes also? We only want codes from LVH001 to LVH999 to end up in the result not LWH001 to LWH999. The database seems to treat V and W as equal. How to accomplish this?

Collation and character type is "sv_SE.UTF-8"
PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on Linux

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm pretty certain using LIKE will be subjected the collation as well.

Comment: See the related [Sort list of tuples considering locale (swedish ordering)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sweedish collation is almost certainly the problem here.

Try collating the expression in the where clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT a < ('foo' COLLATE "fr_FR") FROM test1;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Swedish collation is the problem here.

With Swedish collation in the sql question I get the following result.

```
sql: select lgrplats1 
from verkstad.lager
where lgrplats1  >= ('LVH402' COLLATE "sv_SE") and lgrplats1 < ('LVH403' COLLATE "sv_SE")
order by lgrplats1;
```

Result with included W at the end:

```
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LWH402"
```

The when with French collation.

```
sql: select lgrplats1 
from verkstad.lager
where lgrplats1  >= ('LVH402' COLLATE "fr_FR") and lgrplats1 < ('LVH403' COLLATE "fr_FR")
order by lgrplats1;

Result now without W:
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
"LVH402"
```

I had to include the collation in the "WHERE" clause to make work, just as  Denis pointed out.